# How to prompt user to download java applet in firefox?

Tags: java, html

I'm planning using a java based file uploader (There's an add-on to upload directories.)
http://www.jfileupload.com/products/demo/applet_http.html

Attached are the images in firefox, chrome and safari if you do not have java installed on your computer.
[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]

Firefox does not notify the user that java is not installed.  How do you determine if java is installed and then prompt the user to download the java applet in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/launch.html#launching